# How can I make this var be accessible by other classes?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, var

So I'm making a simple game based on the SadConsole library and there is this var which position I want to reset when a function is called by a different class. But I am not able to access it. Any ways of fixing it?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SadConsole.Components;
using SadConsole;
using SadConsole.Themes;
using SadConsole.Controls;
using Console = SadConsole.Console;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace SAD
{
    class MainConsole: Console
    {
        
        public MainConsole() : base(80,25)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            var console = new Console(80, 25);
            var Control = new ControlsConsole(80,25);
            Children.Add(Control);
            console.IsVisible = true;
            var button = new SadConsole.Controls.Button(10, 5) // THIS VAR. I WANT ITS POSITION TO BE RESET BUT I CAN ACCESS IT
            {
                Text = "Press",
                Position = new Point(5, 5),
                Theme = new ButtonLinesTheme()
            };
            button.Click += (s, a) => button.Position = new Point(random.Next(1, 81), random.Next(1,26));
            Control.Add(button);

           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define variable Globally with public modifier.

Comment: @user_mat What do you mean by *globally*? There are no *global variables* in C#.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto its just that the library requires Microsoft.Xna for various reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring the variable inside your constructor, you should make it a `public` -- this will make it available also outside your assembly -- or `internal` -- this will make it available for all classes within the same assembly -- property.

```
using foo;
...

namespace SAD {

    class MainConsole: Console
    {

        public SadConsole.Controls.Button TheButton {get; private set;}
        public MainConsole() : base(80,25) {
           ...
           TheButton = new SadConsole.Controls.Button(10,5) {...}
        }
    }
}
```

The `private` setter ensures, that `TheButton` can only be set from within the `MainConsole` class, but the getter is `public` so once, the property is set, you can access `TheButton` from anywhere else in the code, where you have an instance of your `MainConsole` class.